# Jquery Drag and Drop over sortable list

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

UPDATE:  For anyone seeking this sort of answer....the answer below was correct.  I have updated the jsfiddle with the corrected code.

I have a jquery drag and drop list created.  Basically I can drag and drop "Fieldsets" in to a div.  Then I can reorder/sort those fieldsets.  I want to be able to drag and drop a "field" into the Fieldsets which are already in the sortable div.  The fields have to be dropped into the fieldset and not the sortable list of fieldsets (this holding the place of a fieldset.

Right now everything is working except the Field will not append into the fieldset.  First I drag Fieldset 1 into the sortable div to the right.  Then I drag a the tile titled "Field One" into the Fieldset 1 below the line "Drop fields here!".  But the field will not append to that fieldset.

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/humphrey_brent/hdb0epx6/31/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#drop-area").droppable({

    accept: '.ui-draggable:not(.draggableField)',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
      clone.addClass('.connectedSortable')
      clone.removeClass('.ui-draggable');
      if (clone.hasClass('dropped')) {
            return false;
        }
        clone.addClass('.connectedSortable').addClass('dropped');

      $(this).append(clone);

    }
  });

    $(".fieldDroppable").droppable({
    // accept: '.draggableField:not(.ui-draggable)',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
      $(this).append(clone);
    }
  });

  $(".ui-draggable").draggable({
    opacity: 1.0,
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
    $(".draggableField").draggable({
    opacity: 1.0,
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });

  $("#drop-area").sortable();
  $("#drop-area").disableSelection();

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated code for `$("#drop-area")`:

```
$("#drop-area").droppable({
    accept: '.ui-draggable:not(.draggableField)',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
      clone.addClass('.connectedSortable')
      clone.removeClass('.ui-draggable');
      if (clone.hasClass('dropped')) {
            return false;
        }
        clone.addClass('.connectedSortable').addClass('dropped');

      $(this).append(clone);

      var fieldsDroppable = $('#drop-area .ui-draggable:last-child .fieldDroppable');

      fieldsDroppable.droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
          $(this).append(clone);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

I have added this part:

```
var fieldsDroppable = $('#drop-area .ui-draggable:last-child .fieldDroppable');
fieldsDroppable.droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        $(this).append(clone);
    }
});
```

The reason why it didn't work earlier because after you add droppable element into that black area, you don't re-register jQuery event for dropped element (fieldset + fields) and because of this, it doesn't allow to drop "fields" into it.

Comment: Thank you for working on it.  I am trying to make sure the "Field One" only drops into the "Fieldset" element.  By removing the "not..." it allows the Field One to be dropped in the sortable Fieldset list.  I am trying to only drop the Field into the previously dropped FIeldset.

Comment: @Brent I have updated my answer. I hope that solves your problem!

Comment: @Brent I'm glad that worked for you. :) Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer as it really helps me!

Comment: Edvid, I am reading up on the re-registering jQuery events.  Thanks for not only fixing it but explaining the problem.

Comment: Can you help me figure out how to restrict dropping into the fieldset to fields only.  So only allow class "fieldsDroppable" to be dropped into the fieldset.  So I do not nest fieldsets inside fieldsets?

Comment: After `fieldsDroppable.droppable({` add `accept: '.draggableField',` line and it should be solved.

Comment: Works.  Thanks again.

Comment: Is it possible to change the coding to allow dragging the field from one fieldset to another?  So once multiple fieldsets are dropped in the working area and a field is dropped in one of those fieldsets, is it possible to allow moving fields from one fieldset to another?

Comment: @Brent While it's possible, of course, I'm not an expert and it might be difficult to achieve (I'm not sure, though). You might need to ask a different question for that. :)